# emitting data via socket on browser close /window close

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I need to send data to nodejs server via socket.io when the user closes the browser tab  .

I tried doing :

```
var data={};
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
// i have a object to be sent 
data.data1='abcd';
data.data2=1234;
socket.emit("senddata",data);
}
```

This code works when the user navigates around  clicking links on the site but doesnot work  when the user closes the browser tab

I also tried configuring the socket io on server side as below .. thinking the error may be due to socket connection being closed before emitting data:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
io.configure(function () {
io.set('close timeout',12000);
});
```

It also didnt work most of the time.

I also tried this on client side:

```
var socket = require('socket.io').listen(80, {
"sync disconnect on unload":false
});
```

It also did not work

I had tried receiving data like this

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.on('senddata', function (data) {
// data processing
});
});
```

please ..help me with this problem..thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

When user connects - register on server side the time it happened.
Socket.IO has heart beating and pinging functionality. So just subscribe to `disconnect` event on server side and once it happens - means client disconnected - and you have on server time when client had connection. So that way you have timespan of client session.

Do not trust client to tell you any time or important data, as client can simply 'lie' - which leads to hacks/cheats/bugs on your server-side.

There is no reliable way to send data just before disconnect from client-side at all. There is nothing in Socket.IO for that, nor in just one of transports (WebSockets). As well as there is too many different scenarios of disconnection (power off, force close, ethernet cable out, wifi lose, etc).

Comment: thanks for reply,but i have a data object to be sent.. that was just an example.. sorry my example was misleading..i have edited the question again...

Comment: There is no reliable way to do so as there is many browser implementations as well as scenarios of closing connection.
Specification of WebSockets do not states anything regarding that as well.